# webix Export toExcel customizing data

Tags: javascript, html, web, export-to-excel, webix

I tried this code in webix

```
  webix.toExcel($$("datatableTab"), {
    filename: "Data_Diff",
    name: "Name"
  });
```

and it dumped everything in my datatable (datatableTab).
But in certain cells I have data like

```
"<span style='color:blue;'>00000000</span><span style='color:LimeGreen;'>000300EE</span>"
```

Which I want it to be **LHS:00000000,RHS:000300EE**

I tried this

```
filterHTML:true
```

and it too printed in Excel as **00000000000300EE**

How do I customize my Excel cell output?

### Links I refered:

- Link for Databable:
  https://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.datatable.html
- Link for
  toExcel: https://docs.webix.com/datatable__exporttoexcel.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the `columns.template` setting:

```js
webix.toExcel($$("myDataTable"), {
    columns:{
        "title":{
            template: obj => { /* your code here */ }
        },
    }
});
```

In there, use `const htmlFilter = /<[^>]*>/gi;` to replace tags with something you need to show instead (or just remove them) and also find and display non-HTML strings in the way that you need.
E.g. https://snippet.webix.com/j5vm2f39